# How to validate a parameter before passing it to a React hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

Here is an example of my code. I want to get a specific element using the id from the URL (NextJS). I want to validate the id first that useElement does not run without a meaning.

```
const {id} = router.query

// Make sure id is not undefined
const element = useElement(id)
```

##### Approach 1

The following code snippet would make sense, but it does not work because React always needs the same number of hooks.

> Error: React has detected a change in the order of Hooks called by
> Foo. This will lead to bugs and errors if not fixed. For
> more information, read the Rules of Hooks:
> https://reactjs.org/link/rules-of-hooks

```
const {id} = router.query

if (!id) {
    return null
}

const element = useElement(id)
```

##### Approach 2

I also thought of validating directly inside my custom hook. However, React does not allow that.

> Uncaught Error: Should have a queue. This is likely a bug in React.
> Please file an issue.

```
export function useElement(id) {
  const [element, setElement] = useState()

  if(!id) {
      return undefined
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    ...
  })

  return element
}
```

What is the best approach to solving this issue?

Comment: Your hooks should never be conditional, which is the case in both your approaches. Can you explain more on what you're trying to do?  Does `useElement` really have to be a hook? https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level

Comment: The hook `useElement` does not eliminate the problem of `id` being `nullish`. If this is for url path parameter handling, (maybe to build an API call), then your front-end should handle the subsequent HTTP Response body appropriately. If this is however an internal `navigator` call, then the parent page should not attempt to navigate to a child page by using an invalid navigator route property (such as `undefined`), i.e. the parent page should validate its navigator props before passing it.

Comment: @Enve The useElement hook fetches a element from an API and caches it. It would also work without a hook, but I need this element often and it is convenient as a hook.

Comment: I cannot think of a way to achieve what you want. As @matabeitt above said you should either let the request go through and handle the API error, or avoid mounting this component if the `id` is invalid and show an error message instead.

Comment: Thank you for your help! As pointed out, I think hooks are not the right solution for my use case.

Comment: Can't you simply move the `id` validation inside the `useEffect` in the custom hook, before fetching the element from the API?